# Creating a Wordpress Submenu without admin menu link

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a plugin. This is source code :

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'hotel_bid_hook');
function hotel_bid_hook()
{
    add_submenu_page("edit.php?post_type=oteller","Hotel Bids", "Hotel Bids", "manage_options", "hotel-bids", "hotel_bid_page");
}
function hotel_bid_page() {
        // Displays a list of bids for hotels and an EDIT button for every bid
}
```

As you see, there is a Hotel Bids page which list all bids. I want to create one more page, too. This page has a HTML form for editing bids. I'm modifing my source code like this :

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'hotel_bid_hook');
function hotel_bid_hook()
{
    add_submenu_page("edit.php?post_type=oteller","Hotel Bids", "Hotel Bids", "manage_options", "hotel-bids", "hotel_bid_page");
    add_submenu_page("edit.php?post_type=oteller","Edit Hotel Bids", "Edit Hotel Bids", "manage_options", "edit-hotel-bid", "edit_hotel_bid");
}
function hotel_bid_page() {
        // Displays a list of bids for hotels and an EDIT button for every bid
        // Edit buttons will be like this : <a href="?page=edit-hotel-bid&hotelID=1">
}
function edit_hotel_bid()
{
   // HTML Web form
}
```

But this time, there is a **Edit Hotel Bids** link under **oteller** custom post type.

[image]

There shouldn't be a **Edit Hotel Bids** link here. This page will be shown only user click to EDIT button. Which function should i use instead of `add_submenu_page()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer found on this question : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1778/admin-config-screen-without-menu/1812#1812